# Routing with Heex

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I'm updating the phoenix LiveView to Heex templates and I'm stuck to how to update `Routing.page_path`

How can I correctly update to Heex template in this case?

```
<a href="<%= Routes.page_path(@socket, :index) %>">
  <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Acompanhante" width="150" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quoted `href` and surround the value with `{}`.

```
<a href={Routes.page_path(@socket, :index)}>
  <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Acompanhante" width="150" />
</a>
```

See, for example,
https://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/phoenix-1.6-released